# How can i access the Open Policy Agent Command Line via Docker Desktop in Windows 10

Tags: docker-compose, windows-10, open-policy-agent

I am attempting to learn the various features of something called Open Policy Agent because I think it may be a useful tool in a microservices based application.

Here is a link to the 'Running with Docker' section of the documentation for this application: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/deployments/#running-with-docker

Currently, I am running Docker using the Docker Desktop in a Windows 10 environment and I already have a docker-compose file set up for my main application which includes various docker images.  My thoughts were that I could simply add the latest openpolicyagent image as well as the openpolicyagent demo-restful api so that I could begin learning about the service.  To do this, I added the following lines to my docker-compose.yml:

```
  opa:
    image: openpolicyagent/opa:0.34.2
    ports:
      - 8181:8181
    command:
      - "run"
      - "--server"
      - "--log-level=debug"
      - "api_authz.rego"
    volumes:
      - C:\Sites\prosaurus\policy\api_authz.rego:/api_authz.rego

  api_server:
    image: openpolicyagent/demo-restful-api:latest
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      - OPA_ADDR=http://opa:8181
      - POLICY_PATH=/v1/data/httpapi/authz
```

This appears to have worked in that I can go to localhost:8181 and i see the Query and Input Data (JSON) boxes as I presume is supposed to happen, however I would like to test some of the command line functions as are mentioned here:

https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/#2-try-opa-eval

However I can not seem to access the command line of the docker container which is running the OPA agent.  The way I have attempted this is via the Docker Desktop application GUI in  Windows.  In this application I can see all of the docker instances which are running and each one has an option to run the CLI (you click the button and the cli opens).  They all  work except for the OPA one.  When I click on that one a cmd window opens for a split second, displays something too fast for me to read it and then closes.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPA can be run in a few different ways, and `opa eval` is distinctly different from running OPA as a server, i.e. `opa run --server`.

When you run OPA as a server - which is how you'd normally run OPA in production - you query OPA for policy decisions through OPA's [REST API](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/rest-api/#data-api).

`opa eval` on the other hand is more like a Swiss army knife of OPA, allowing you to quickly evaluate a rule or expression given some provided policy and data.

You can think of them as two entirely different tools.

Comment: Ah, i think part of my problem is that I don't fully understand what the heck is going on in docker either.  I do see the command section with "run" "--server" etc.. so i'm guessing that is how OPA is being "run as a server".  Perhaps if i were to remove that i could ssh into the container and run the eval command as i have seen...  Going to research this more (time allotting as it is a holiday).  thanks for the insight

Comment: Any time @DallasCaley - I'd recommend downloading the OPA executable without Docker first just to learn how it works and all the commands available. And the [OPA Slack](https://slack.openpolicyagent.org/) is a great place for learning as well.